# Apache Redirect: RewriteRule based on Cookie Value

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, cookies, url-rewriting

I'm using Apache 2.2 and want to add a string to the request URI if it is not already part of the URI. This string is dynamic and stored in a cookie called "mycookie". If the cookie value is "root" no rewrite should be performed.

**Case 1: Rewrite required**
mycookie=foo
uri=/bar -> uri=/foo/bar (/foo added)

**Case 2: No rewrite required**
mycookie=foo
uri=/foo/bar -> no rewrite (URI already starts with /foo)

**Case 3: No rewrite, cookie value ignored**
mycookie=root
uri=/bar -> no rewrite (value "root" is ignored)

```
#no redirect for cookie value „root“
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*mycookie=([a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+).* [NC]
RewriteCond %1 =root
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,NC]

#no rewrite required if cookie value is already part of the request uri
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.* mycookie=([a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+).* [NC]

# Wrong syntax
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/%1/.*$ [NC]
# Correct syntax
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)::/\1/?


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,NC]

#add cookie value to path: eg.  /bar -> /cookieval/bar
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.* mycookie =([a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/%1$1 [R,L]
```

**The problem** is that requests are rewriten within a loop. -> /foo/foo/foo/../foo/bar

**Solution** Backreferences (%1) can only be used on the left side of a RewriteCond

Comment: I figured out the problem. You can use a backreference (%1) in a RewriteCond only on the left side. I had to change RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/%1/.*$ [NC] to RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)::/\1/?

Answer (score 1):

Backreferences (%1) can only be used on the left side of a RewriteCond

Changed  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/%1/.*$ [NC]

To RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)::/\1/?